# How can I get what table(s) an embedded Power BI report is using?

Tags: javascript, powerbi-embedded

I'd like to dynamically create custom filters like this one :

```
const filter = {
    $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
    target: {
        table: "tableName",
        column: "columnName"
    },
    operator: "In",
    values: ["value1", "value2"]
};
```

To do this, I'll need to know the table name that the currently displayed report is using. Is there a way to request this through the Power BI Embedded JS API?

Edit:
using the dataSelected event, I can parse out the table of a selected datapoint.

```
report.on('dataSelected', function (event) {
    console.log(event.detail.dataPoints[0].values[0].target.table);
});
```

Is there maybe a way to programmatically select all of the data to trigger the dataSelected event so I can retrieve the table? (I know it's yucky)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get Data feature was just released in Power BI Embedded JS SDK: 
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Export-Data

This allows you to get the data rows (Summarized or Underlying) from within a certain visual in a report.

This should also return the original table columns, that way you can make your filters more robust, and with less workarounds such as that `'dataselected'` event listener.

Simply use:

```js
// Exports visual data
visual.exportData(models.ExportDataType.Summarized, 100)
  .then(function (data) {
    Log.log(data);
  })
```